# Fade in / out on hover

Tags: jquery, css

When you hover on `#one`, `#first` gets the class `.hidden`. I've got my script to fade out `.hidden` using `transition:ease-in 0.3s;` but I can't get the fade in to work. I tried adding `transition:ease-in 0.3s;` to `#first` but that didn't work.

*EDIT* Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lbvmgh21/   I just noticed that after initiating the script just once (hovering the over for the first time) any subsequent hover fades in and out properly.

```
$("#one").on({
    mouseover: function () {
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#first").removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');
        }, 0);
    },
    mouseout: function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $("#first").css({
            'opacity': '0'
        }).addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you share your css and html as well, or preferably show what you have in a jsfiddle?

Comment: If your using jQuery why not just use [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) or [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)/[`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)?

Comment: @Brian added fidde to OP

Comment: I'm confused, your JSFiddle appears to work for me, the images fade in and out. Is there something I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the opacity style inside of the class 'hidden' in your css, remove it from the javascript... then your removeClass and addClass transition should work properly. Also, I personally don't see the need for the timer.

```
$("#one").on({
    mouseover: function () {
        $("#first").removeClass('hidden');
    },
    mouseout: function () {
        $("#first").addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

Comment: But it doesn't really have a fading effect to it.

Comment: #first needs to have two classes, class1 and class2. class1 has the transition and the opacity set to 0. class 2 (hidden) has the opacity: 1 and that's it no extra css in class2 (not even transition). The button should always have class 1, and just remove/add class2 and it should work.

Comment: @Dude2TheN Thanks, that worked. This is a side question but how can I get each <a> to not affect each other when hovered. When you hover over "Mar" you can see that "Lights Out" shifts a little.

Comment: put the <a> inside a <div> and set the positioning on the <div> to inline-block (http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html), also set a manual px or % size

Comment: @Dude2TheN  I put them in `.name` but I don't want to set a specific size. I would just like to use `width:auto;` since I don't know what size they'll be. https://jsfiddle.net/Lbvmgh21/1/

Answer (score 1):

check this demo. does it work properly?

[demo](http://codepen.io/mugukamil/pen/aOaXYx)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#one").on({
        mouseover: function() {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                $(".first").removeClass('hidden').css('opacity', '1');
            }, 0);
        },
        mouseout: function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            $(".first").css({
                'opacity': '0',
                'transition': 'ease-in 0.3s'
            }).addClass('hidden');
        }
    });
});
```